# List different case duplicates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, case-sensitive

I'm quite new to databases and I'm trying to get a list of duplicate values with different case values for example in my database I have

```
id | email
---------------------
1  | first@email.com
2  | First@email.com  
3  | second@mail.com
4  | third@email.com
```

I can select the duplicate values with

```
 SELECT count(*) as 'duplicates', lower(email) as 'email'
 FROM   my_table
 GROUP  BY lower(email)
 HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

this returns:

```
duplicates | email
------------------------
2          |  first@email.com
```

Bu I would like to return the two different case emails as well, for example:

```
duplicates | email           | email2
-----------------------------------------
2          | first@email.com | First@email.com
```

Note: from the initial query I can see that there are no more than 2 duplicates (this might make the query simpler)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: it's on Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `array_agg()` so you get all of them:

```
SELECT count(*) as duplicates, lower(email) as email,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT email) as all_emails
FROM my_table
GROUP BY lower(email)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18cf1cd0465ba5fc0b6360c583b5b51f) is a db<>fiddle.

In SQL Server, you can use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT count(*) as duplicates, lower(email) as email,
       STRING_AGG(email, ',') as all_emails
FROM my_table
GROUP BY lower(email)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Unfortunately, `DISTINCT` is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I mistakenly said it was on prostgreSQL but it's on Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: STRING_AGG() is only available on SQL Server 2017 and I'm on 2012, is there any other function I can use instead of STRING_AGG()?

Answer (score 0):

With you knowing ahead of time you have no more than two duplicates, you can very easily do:

```
select Min(email) Email, Max(email) Email2
from t
group by lower(email)
having Count(*)=2
```